# How to interface MLX90614 temperature sensor with Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3b+, i2c, python-3

I have a `mlx90614` sensor and I am interfacing it with `raspberry pi 3 B+`. I am using `adafruit` library python. Below is the code:

```
import Adafruit_GPIO.I2C as I2C

I2C.require_repeated_start()

class Melexis:

    def __init__(self, address=0x5A):
        self._i2c = I2C.Device(address,busnum=1)

    def readAmbient(self):
        return self._readTemp(0x06)

    def readObject1(self):
        return self._readTemp(0x07)

    def readObject2(self):
        return self._readTemp(0x08)

    def _readTemp(self, reg):
        temp = self._i2c.readS16(reg)
        print("raw temp {}".format(temp))
        temp = temp * .02 - 273.15
        return temp

sensor = Melexis()
t = sensor.readObject1()
a = sensor.readAmbient()
print("Object: {}C , Ambiant: {}C".format(round(t, 3), round(a, 3)))
```

Output:

```
raw temp 0
raw temp 0
Object: -273.15C , Ambiant: -273.15C
```

I have connected the `sda` pin of sensor to `sda` pin 3 of pi and `scl` pin of sensor to `scl` pin 5 of pi. `vcc` to `3.3v` pin 1 and `gnd` to `gnd`. But I am not able to read the temperature values and it only shows `0*c`. I have checked the output of `ls /dev` and I can see the `i2c` device connected as `i2c-1`. When I am doing `i2cdetect -y 1`, I am getting below output:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
10: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f
20: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f
30: 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f
40: 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f
50: 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f
60: 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f
70: 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
```

As far as I know, this sensor has address 0x5a and I can see this in above output but still not able to understand above output. Can anyone please help me here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is a wiring error.

When an `i2cdetect` probe shows all addresses it suggests `SDA` is being pulled to ground.

Comment: Other thing to check - there are 3v and 5v versions.  Not sure what gets reported if you under power it (would expect zilch TBH).

Comment: If `SDA` is being pulled to ground, then what should I do, connect it to 3.3v

Comment: @Andyroo tried with 5v, its still the same

Comment: @SAndrew SDA is already being pulled to 3V3 (via an on-board resistor),  The indication is that a faulty connection is pulling it to ground.  A wrong wire, a solder splash, a faulty unit.  You will need to investigate to find the source.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an Arduino? Then I suggest you connect the MLX90614 to the Arduino and run the I2C scanner code. The I2C scanner code returns the I2C address. Thus, you will be able to verify if your device's I2C address is really 0x5A or anything else.